# How the highlight text in PS1 environment variable

Tags: linux, unix, aix, ps1

Currently my PS1 environment variable is displaying as shown below:

[image]

The below image is what I would like my PS1 environment variable to display as:

[image]

The below is how my PS1 environment variable is set as:

```
export PS1='$LOGIN@'`hostname`':$PWD> '
```

Unfortunately I am unsure of how to change my PS1 environment variable to give me what I want and everything I have tried does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should give you the prompt you're looking for:

```
export PS1="\[\033[38;5;0m\]\[\033[48;5;253m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\[\033[48;5;-1m\]:\w\#\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Add it to your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

You can adjust the background color behind the user@host part by changing the value 253. For example, 240 gives you dark grey and 255 white.

There is a number of bash PS1 generators that you can use to customize your bash prompts. For example, try http://bashrcgenerator.com/

Comment: I added the line you provided and I get this [033[38;5;0m][033[48;5;15m]'chrisk@'dcdev3':/home/chrisk> '[]. I used this 'export PS1="\[\033[38;5;0m\]\[\033[48;5;15m\]\'$LOGIN@'`hostname`':$PWD> '\[$(tput sgr0)\]"' and it does not work

Comment: Maybe try `PS1=$(echo - e "\[\033[38;5;0m\]\[\033[48;5;253m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\[\033[48;5;-1m\]:\w\#\[$(tput sgr0)\]")`

Answer (score 1):

This should help on a AIX Version 7.1

```
bold=`tput smso`
norm=`tput rmso`
PS1="${bold}$LOGNAME@`hostname`:${norm}\${PWD}# "
export PS1
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit this post: insert four spaces before program-lines. Or simply: `inv=$(tput smso); norm=$(tput rmso); export PS1="$inv"text"$norm"`